# AXE on Angular 7+

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, accessibility

When using AXE (accessibility), I receive this error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="table-style">
    <table mat-table class="mat-elevation-z8 table-format">
       <ng-container matColumnDef="item">
          <th class="info--header" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Something</th>
          <td class="info-header2" mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>
              <p>Hello</p>
          </td>
       </ng-container>
       <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
       <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: where's your `<tr>`?

Comment: @Marc I updated my Q

Comment: You should look into `a11y` (https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview). From the error, it looks like AXE doesn't agree with angulars HTML setup (before it's compiled). There is probably some way to integrate AXE within Angular, but probably not without some extra configuration.

Comment: @panleychan That link is invalid. This is Angular Material. The OP doesn't have a choice in structure since Angular Material requires this.

Comment: I do have mat-cell

Answer (score 1):

`<tbody role="rolegroup">` is only valid if the rows within it are labelled as `<tr role="row">`.

You should also then have `<td role="cell">` within each `<tr>` for valid `aria`.

The is what the error is telling you "you have this role (`role="rolegroup"`) but in order to be valid it expects child elements (`role="row"`)".

I am guessing some or all of your items do not have a role (best guess would be the `ng-container` but without seeing the generated HTML it is hard to be sure).

Your generated HTML should follow the following pattern:-

```
<table role="table">   
  <thead role="rowgroup">      
     <tr role="row">        
       <th role="columnheader">Head 1</th>
       <th role="columnheader">Head 2</th>      
     </tr>    
  </thead>
  <tbody role="rowgroup">     
     <tr role="row">        
       <td role="cell">1a</td>
       <td role="cell">2a</td>
     </tr>
     <tr role="row">
       <td role="cell">1b</td>
       <td role="cell">2b</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Inspect your generated HTML, if any of the `row`, `columnheader` or `cell` roles are not defined add them manually.

[This article from mozilla is a good starting place to learn about `rowgroup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Rowgroup_Role)

Comment: I am using Angular Material

Comment: That makes no difference, the roles can be added where they are needed, the structure is just a guide as to what needs to appear where in a table. Use the inspector to see what gets generated in the end HTML and 'fill in the gaps' on the rows and cells with any missing `aria-roles`.